# Check array for consecutive sets of 1s and 0s

Tags: c++11

I am trying to access elements in a DArray (which I have created by copying elements from a linked list) 3 at a time, searching for sets of 3 consecutive 1s and 0s. For ex: if indices 0 through 2 hold the values of 1 1 1, my output would be a 1. If indices 3 through 5 hold the values 0 0 0, my output would be 0. If indices 6 through 8 hold a mixture of 1s and 0s, the output would be nothing. I've tried several approaches and cannot seem to find one that works right. Does anyone have any ideas? This is not a homework assignment.

Comment: Can you eleborate on what a `DArray` is? Also, posting the code of at least one of your approaches that didn't work would be useful.

Comment: I apologize for my shorthand. DArray stands for dynamic array.

Comment: I'm really not sure how to post code correctly. Sorry.

Comment: `int* zerosOnes = new int[numberOfElements];
Node* temp = last;
if (numberOfElements == 0)
 cerr << "Stack is empty.";
 else if (numberOfElements >= 3)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements - 1; i++)
  {
   if (temp->getData() == 0)
   temp = temp->getPrevLink();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements - 1; i += 3)
  {
   if (zerosOnes[i] == 0 && zerosOnes[i] == zerosOnes[i + 1]
    && zerosOnes[i] == zerosOnes[i + 2])
    cout << "0 ";
   else if (zerosOnes[i] == 1 && zerosOnes[i] == zerosOnes[i + 1]
    && zerosOnes[i] == zerosOnes[i + 2])
    cout << "1 ";
 }
}`